# Merging pandas dataframes based on lists of paired indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`, and a fairly complicated set of logical statements that I have to run as a separate function to merge them. That function returns a pair of indices for the row in `df1` and the row in `df2`, that looks right now like

`matches = [[1,2,7,14], [1,2,7,14], [3,8]]`

something like that so that `matches[idx]` has a list of indices in `df2` to merge with the row `df1.loc[idx]`, so rows 0 and 1 in `df1` would merge with rows 1,2,7,14 in `df2`, and on.

How would I merge `df1` with `df2` on these lists? The logic is prohibitive to try to run through pandas in terms of speed, so I have to start with these lists of matches between the dataframes.

Comment: Try `pd.concat([df1, pd.Series(matches, name='match')], axis=1).explode('match').merge(df2, left_on='match', right_index=True)`. Should work for numerical indices.

Comment: That's the solution, thanks @MYousefi!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @MYousefi, this was the solution:

> Try
>
> `pd.concat([df1, pd.Series(matches, name='match')], axis=1).explode('match').merge(df2, left_on='match', right_index=True)`
>
> Should work for numerical indices.